# How can I access data inside ngOnInit in Angular?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, synchronization, rxjs-observables, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am using subscribe to get data inside ngOnInit. I want to do some operation based on the value received from it. But when I am trying to access it in ngOnInit, it is undefined.

My class :

```
export class UserPropertiesTO {
  verifierRoles: string[];
  rolesWhichCannotBeOwners: string[];
  showcaseRoles: string[];
  unManageRoles: string[];
}
```

My component.ts file

```
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit {

  userPropertiesTO: UserPropertiesTO;
 
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }
  
  init(){
    this.userPropertiesTO = new UserPropertiesTO();
 
    this.onRoleLoad(() => {
      this.userService.retrieveUserProperties().subscribe(data => {
        this.userPropertiesTO = data;
      })

      if(this.userPropertiesTO.showcaseRoles.includes(someValue) {   //it is showing undefined here
        // want to do some operation here
      }
    }); 
      
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.init();
  }
```

And following is my retrieveUserProperties method in service file

```
 retrieveUserProperties(): Observable<UserPropertiesTO> {
    return this.http.get<UserPropertiesTO>('/user/UserProperties');
  }
```

Comment: Move the `if` statement inside the `subscribe` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable is asynchronous. Based on your current code, the `if` statement will be executed synchronously without waiting for the observable to be returned. Thus that's why the `userPropertiesTO.showcaseRoles` is `undefined`.

Move the `if` statement within the `subscribe` function so that it will be executed when the observable/response is returned.

```
this.userService.retrieveUserProperties().subscribe(data => {
  this.userPropertiesTO = data;

  if (this.userPropertiesTO.showcaseRoles.includes(someValue) {
    // want to do some operation here
  }
})
```